# Linker not recognizing some #includes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, include

I have a VC++ solution with multiple projects and multiple namespaces. Each project has its own namespace, and some projects have multiple namespaces.

Sometimes, when I reference an object from another project I will end up with "unresolved external symbol" errors even though I #included the header file and referenced the object through it's namespace (Namespace::object). In order to get rid of the linker errors I have to also #include the cpp file, then I get warnings that the symbol was defined twice.

This is very hackish and I don't like hackish.

I know that I need to go through and look at all the include dependencies, since something's obviously screwed up, but I haven't been able to find any major problems as of yet.

In the mean time, does anyone have any suggestions for anything obvious to check or any common causes to this problem?

Comment: Pretty vague.  Using an #include isn't enough, you also have to tell the linker about it.  It needs to link the *implementation* of the class.  Using #pragma comment(lib, "whatever.lib") can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual C++, Go to your project properties, under `Linker > Input`, you should add the compiled `.lib` file of the project you are depending on.
Like others have stated, the compilation unit you are missing has nothing to do with files you `#include` (which are only relevant for compilation, not linkage)

Comment: Perhaps by including the cpp file, it got compiled into your project. Maybe more than one file included the header that included the cpp file, and then it was defined twice.

Answer (score 4):

"unresolved external symbols" are *linker* errors. And linking doesn't care about what gets #included (not unless there are #pragmas involved). All linking cares about is what you explicitly state you're linking with.

Those other projects you're trying to use must produce a library or something when you compile them, right? You should link to those in your project settings.

Answer (score 2):

Linking object files is not done using `#include` preprocessor commands, but through VC++ itself or (non-standard) `#pragma` commands..